# First non-repeated character in a string in c

Tags: optimization, c, strings, array

> Write an efficient function to find the first non-repeated character
>   in a string. For example, the first non-repeated character in "total"
>   is 'o' and the first non-repeated character in "teeter" is 'r'.

Please see my solution and give me some feedback and suggestions for improving and optimizing it if needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100                /* max size of input string */
#define LIM 5                   /* max number of inputs */
char repeat_ch(const char *);   /* return first non-repeated character */
int main(void)
{
    char line[SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    while(i < LIM && gets(line))
    {
        ch = repeat_ch(line);
        if(ch != NULL)
            printf("1st non-repeated character: %c\n", ch);
        else
                printf("There is no unique character in a string: %s\n", line);
        i++;
    }

}

char repeat_ch(const char *string)
{
    char array[130] = {0};
    char *p = string;

    /* store each character in array, use ascii code as an index for character
     * increment each time the same character appears in a string
     */
    while(*p)                               // stop when '\0' encountered
    {
        array[*p]+=1;
        p++;
    }
    while(*string)
    {
        if(array[*string] == 1)
            return *string;         // stop when unique character found
        string++;
    }

    return *string;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alex, it looks quite efficient. There are some issues that I see:

- `gets` should never be used. Use `fgets` (but note that you will have to strip the trailing `\n`)
- define `main` at the end to avoid the need for a prototype for `repeat_ch`
- declare `repeat_ch` as static
- your limit does not work as `i` is not incremented.  But why not stop on
  reading an empty string rather than limit the number of loops?
- NULL is normally defined as `(void *) 0` so comparing a char with NULL is
  wrong.  The compiler will warn you of that.  Just use 0 or better '\0'

In `repeat_ch`

- function name is inaccurate - function looks for a **non**-repeated char.
- the two // comments are noisy (ie. don't tell reader anything)
- `array` would be better sized 256
- `p` should be `const`
- for-loops would be better

  ```
  for (const char *p=string; *p; ++p) {
      array[*p] += 1;
  }
  for (const char *p=string; *p; ++p) {
      if (array[*p] == 1) {
          return *p;
      }
  }
  return '\0';
  ```

Comment: thanks for feedback was really useful. Have added "i" as it was my copy-paste typo.

Comment: +1: Very good analysis.  The only things I can see that you didn't mention are trivia: (1) erratic indentation in `main()` and (2) use of `if(...)` etc instead of `if (...)`.  The omitted `return 0;` from `main()` is OK in C99 or later, though personally I think that rule was a mistake and always include it.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is good enough for small scale string, but in practical life, this problem needs to deal with string having length in millions eg DNA string etc.

2) You can improve it by not traversing over the string for the second time, but maintain the first occurrence of the each character with the number of its occurrence.
Sorting like structure -

```
typedef struct charStruct {
   int count;
   int index;
}cStruct;

//...

cStruct *count = (cStruct *)calloc(sizeof(cStruct),256);
```

malloc for 256 characters (if dealing with ASCII) and use this structure, that will give you huge improvement in practical solution.